# php json_encode id column to string

Tags: json, php-5.6

My array is :

```
$response = [
    0 => [
        'id' => 'US',
        'text' => 'United States'
    ],
    1 => [
        'id' => 'CA',
        'text' => 'Canada'
    ],

    2 => [
        'id' => 'FR',
        'text' => 'France'
    ],
...
]
```

When I do a `json_encode` on it, for some reason the `id` value is 0 through the array:

```
{"id":0,"text":"United States"},
{"id":0,"text":"Canada"},
{"id":0,"text":"France"}
```

This only happens if the the column name is `id` as if `json_encode` forces ID to be numeric.

Any idea how to use a string in the `id` column ?

Comment: I just ran your exact code and it works just fine?

Answer (score 0):

You need commas after all of your `'id' => 'XX'` lines. After adding those and running json_encode it worked fine for me, the id's all kept their string values.

Comment: the missing commas are just a typo

Comment: @Alucard In that case your code is working fine for me, json_encode returns `[{"id":"US","text":"United States"},{"id":"CA","text":"Canada"},{"id":"FR","text":"France"}]`. I'm using php 5.6.15.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$response = [
    0 => [
        'id' => 'US',
        'text' => 'United States'
    ],
    1 => [
    'id' => 'CA',
        'text' => 'Canada',
    ],

    2 => [
    'id' => 'FR',
        'text' => 'France'
    ]
];

var_dump(json_encode($response, 20));
```

RESULT:

```
{
    "0": {"id": "US", "text": "United States"},
    "1": {"id": "CA", "text": "Canada"},
    "2": {"id": "FR", "text": "France"}
}
```